# Recursive function to calculate simple path from start to end in a graph

Tags: python, recursion, graph

I wrote a recursive function to find a simple path in a graph (there exists only one path), given list of graph edges as tuples. for example:

`edges = [(0, 10),(2, 16),(4, 5),(6, 24),(7, 6),(8, 23),(9, 25),(10, 14),(11, 1),(12, 19),(13, 22),(14, 15),(15, 11),(16, 7),(17, 21),(18, 13),(19, 17),(20, 8),(21, 3),(22, 20),(23, 12),(24, 9),(25, 18)]`

```py
def get_path(sol, start, end):
    out = []
    for i,j in sol:
        if i == start:
            out.append(i)
            out += get_path(sol, j, end)
        if j == end:
            out.append(j)
    return out
```

However if I cannot get the end node correctly in my return list. If I remove line 7 and 8 the last node will not be present in my solution, and also if I have those lines in the code I get more than one end node in my solution. As an example:

```py
get_path(edges, 2, 3)
path = [2, 16, 7, 11, 15, 14, 10, 22, 13, 18, 25, 21, 17, 19, 12, 9, 24, 6, 8, 20, 23]
```

As we can see end node is `3` which should be last element of the list. I highly appreciate your inputs. Thanks

Comment: I'd ditch this method and go with Dijkstra's algorithm. If your input graph is large, you might find yourself running into stack issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each recursive call in your code will have one iteration where `j == end` is true, and so you will indeed get it added multiple times: just as many as you have recursion depth.

It will work better if you put the end-condition outside of the loop, like this:

```
if start == end:
    return [start]
```

So with that little modification your code would look like this:

```
def get_path(sol, start, end):
    if start == end:
        return [start]
    out = []
    for i,j in sol:
        if i == start:
            out.append(i)
            out += get_path(sol, j, end)
    return out
```

A few other remarks:

- You can perform the two list operations in the `if` block in one go:

  ```
     out += [i] + get_path(sol, j, end)
  ```
- It is very inefficient to iterate through the complete list in each
  recursive call. It would be better to first build a dictionary, keyed
  by the start number. That way you don't have to iterate to find the
  corresponding edge.
- It seems that your code expects the graph to be a chain, without any
  nodes where you have 2 or more outgoing edges. If that would happen, the `if i == start:` block would execute multiple times resulting in an awkward output. It is not too hard to cover for such situations as well

Code:

```
from collections import defaultdict 

def get_path(sol, start, end):
    # Transform to dict
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for i,j in sol:
        d[i] += [j]

    def recur(start):
        if start == end:
            return [start]
        for nxt in d[start]:
            path = recur(nxt)
            if path is not None: 
                return [start] + path
    return recur(start)

edges = [(0, 10),(2, 16),(4, 5),(6, 24),(7, 6),(8, 23),(9, 25),(10, 14),
         (11, 1),(12, 19),(13, 22),(14, 15),(15, 11),(16, 7),(17, 21),
         (18, 13),(19, 17),(20, 8),(21, 3),(22, 20),(23, 12),(24, 9),(25, 18)]

path = get_path(edges, 2, 3)
print (path)
```

### Cyclic graph

Your question is about acyclic graphs since you wrote:

> there exists only one path

But for anyone coming here looking for a solution for cyclic graphs, the above solution would need to be extended so it does not get stuck in a cycle. This can be done by marking nodes as visited:

```
from collections import defaultdict 

def get_path(sol, start, end):
    # Transform to dict
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for i,j in sol:
        d[i] += [j]

    visited = set()
    def recur(start):
        if start == end:
            return [start]
        visited.add(start)
        for nxt in d[start]:
            if nxt not in visited:
                path = recur(nxt)
                if path is not None: 
                    return [start] + path
        visited.remove(start)
    return recur(start)

edges =  [(0,1),(1,0),(0,2),(2,0),(2,3),(3,2)]

path = get_path(edges, 2, 3)
print (path)
```

Note that neither solutions guarantee that the found path is the shortest. But if it is known that there is only one path, it is a memory efficient algorithm.

If there are multiple paths, then a depth-first search cannot stop the search when it finds a path, as there still might be shorter paths to be found. If on the other hand you use a breadth-first search, then you can stop as soon as you find a path.

Comment: For the graph edges = [(0,1),(1,0),(0,2), (2,0), (2,3),(3,2)] you get a loop with your code. I think your code works only for directed graphs without cycles.

Comment: True, but the OP wrote that *"there exists only one path"*, and so their question was for an acyclic graph.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `networkX` for that. You can define a network from the edges and obtain the simple paths between two given nodes. I'm using [`nx.shortest_simple_paths`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.shortest_simple_paths.html#networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.shortest_simple_paths), but you could use `all_simple_paths` to obtain them all:

```
import networkx as nx

G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(edges)
next(nx.shortest_simple_paths(G, 2, 3))
# [2, 16, 7, 6, 24, 9, 25, 18, 13, 22, 20, 8, 23, 12, 19, 17, 21, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I'm aware of that. But I'm trying to minimize dependencies in my program.

Comment: I see. I'd strongly suggest using networkX though for network analysis tasks for a better performance. @MohammadAbdollahi